# Tinymce doesn't work

Tags: forms, symfony, tinymce, textarea

I implemented the Tinymce's plugin, and it works!
In fact, all the text areas now have a text editor.
This is my view.

[image]

The problem is that this is obviously a form, and when I submit it, doesn't submit at all.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please stop adding SOLVED to the title, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Mark one of the answers as the solution instead of changing the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RecipeType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class RecipeType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $currentField;

    protected $entity;

    public function __construct($entity)
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('titolo');
        $builder->add('autore');
        $builder->add('tipologia', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipologia',
            'label' => 'Tipologia',
             'choice_label' => 'name',
        ));
        $builder->add('difficolta','choice',array(
            'choices' => array ('1','2','3','4','5')
        ));
        $builder->add('persone','choice',array(
            'choices' => array ('1','2','3','4','5','6','6+')
        ));
        $builder->add('tempo');
        $builder->add('ingredienti','textarea',array(
            'required' => false,
        ));
        $builder->add('procedimento', 'textarea',array(
            'required' => false,
        ));
        $builder->add('image', 'file', array(
                'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false
            )
        );

          $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $this->currentField = $this->entity->getImage();
                });

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $inputFile = $form->getData();
                    $newImage = $inputFile->getImage();
                    if (is_null($newImage) && !is_null($this->currentField))
                    {
                        $inputFile->setImage($this->currentField);
                    }
                });
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'recipe';
    }
}
```

THE SOLUTION:
In every Textarea field add required false.

```
$builder->add('ingredienti','textarea',array(
                'required' => false,
            ));
            $builder->add('procedimento', 'textarea',array(
                'required' => false,
            ));
```